# Use library compiled with newer Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

say if a 3rd party library has been built with the VS2017 compiler, is it possible to use it in VS2012 solutions?

Comment: This depends on what kind of library, but in the general sense I would say yes, this should be possible, it (probably) depends on other factors than which version of *Visual Studio* that has been used.

Comment: Please understand that a general question can only receive general answers. General answers may not be applicable in a specific case, but in order to get a specific answer you will have to ask a more specific question.

Comment: VS is an IDE and can build libraries for many different languages. You should specify at least what programming language your question is about in order to get a sensible answer.

Comment: Added the programming language: C++

Comment: Generally no, mixing different versions of the C and C++ runtime libraries is a recipe for problems.  Only very careful library design can avoid them, they tend to be too draconian to be taken serious and UB is too easy to induce.  So no standard C++ classes in the public interface, no exceptions thrown across a module boundary, no passing of pointers that are allocated in one module and released in another, no use of global CRT state (like errno) across modules.